# SQL View Query need time interval calculation between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have below View Query. While calculating time interval it only display time interval if check Out is for same date. For example if i check in on 11/12/2017 then it i have to check out with same date 11/12/201 n order to calculate time Interval.

But i want to modify it like if i  checkout on next day (after 12:00 AM midnight) it should also calculate the time interval.can some help  me to modify query to get the desired results?

**Query:**

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[TimeAttendanceQuery]
AS
SELECT TOP (100)    PERCENT 
    dbo.AxPerson.Name,
    dbo.AxPerson.IdNumber  AS EmployeeID,
    dbo.TimeAttendance.Badge, 
    dbo.AxPerson.Id, 
    MIN(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime) AS EntryTime, 

    MAX(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime) AS ExitTime,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, MIN(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime), MAX(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime)) / 60 / 60 / 24 AS NVARCHAR(50)) +
    ':' + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, MIN(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime), MAX(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime)) / 60 / 60 % 24 AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ':' + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, MIN(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime),  MAX(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime)) / 60 % 60 AS NVARCHAR(50))
    AS TimeInterval, 
    dbo.TimeAttendance.Event, 
    dbo.AxPerson.Type AS ShitType, 
    dbo.AxPerson.ShiftDesc, 
    CONVERT(Varchar,dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime, 101) AS EventTIME

FROM
    dbo.AxPerson 
INNER JOIN dbo.TimeAttendance ON dbo.AxPerson.Name = dbo.TimeAttendance.Name
GROUP BY  dbo.AxPerson.Name, dbo.AxPerson.IdNumber, dbo.TimeAttendance.Badge, CONVERT(Varchar, dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime, 101), dbo.         AxPerson.ShiftDesc, dbo.AxPerson.Id, dbo.TimeAttendance.Event,dbo.AxPerson.Type
ORDER BY dbo.AxPerson.Name, EventTime DESC

GO
```

Comment: Do you have a column which determines the event type? is yes what is the value of check-in event and what is the value of checkout event?

Comment: Remove the `TOP(100) PERCENT` and `ORDER BY` as those are superfluous in a view definition. You need to specify `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` statement that uses the view in order to guarantee result set ordering.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @DawoodAwan yes i do have column which tells event is entry r exit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the algorithm you posted, but if you want to get the time difference from two datetimes you can cast the subtraction as time. This works for less than 24 hours.  If you also want the number of days (I think this is only good for less than a year), then you can do the datepart-day  of the difference.

For example:

```
DECLARE @starttime datetime = '2017-11-12 010:20:00'
DECLARE @endtime   datetime = '2017-11-13 08:00:00'

SELECT DATEPART(DAY, @endtime - @starttime) - 1 [Days Passed]
      ,CAST(@endtime - @starttime as time(0)) [Time Passed]
       --WHERE the (0) in time(0) is for the milliseconds to return.
```

Gives output:

```
Days Passed Time Passed
0           21:40:00
```

---

If you don't care about the days, then your code could be modified like this:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[TimeAttendanceQuery]
AS
SELECT Name, EmployeeID, Badge, Id, EntryTime,
       CAST(ExitTime - EntryTime as time(0)) [TimeInterval],
       Event, ShiftType, ShiftDesc
      ,CONVERT(Varchar, EventTime, 101) AS EventTIME
  FROM (
         SELECT
           dbo.AxPerson.Name,
           dbo.AxPerson.IdNumber  AS EmployeeID,
           dbo.TimeAttendance.Badge, 
           dbo.AxPerson.Id, 
           MIN(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime) AS EntryTime,  
           MAX(dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime) AS ExitTime,             
           dbo.TimeAttendance.Event, 
           dbo.AxPerson.Type AS ShiftType, 
           dbo.AxPerson.ShiftDesc, 
           dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime

           FROM dbo.AxPerson INNER JOIN dbo.TimeAttendance 
                                     ON dbo.AxPerson.Name = dbo.TimeAttendance.Name

           GROUP BY  
           dbo.AxPerson.Name, 
           dbo.AxPerson.IdNumber, 
           dbo.TimeAttendance.Badge, 
           dbo.AxPerson.Id, 
           dbo.TimeAttendance.Event,
           dbo.AxPerson.Type
           dbo.AxPerson.ShiftDesc,
           dbo.TimeAttendance.EventTime,
       ) AS dT
```

Comment: This algorithm works with same date check in and out only. I am ok to calculate 24 hour difference time after check in. Can you help me what i can change in current query ?